# Sum of the elements of the ith row up to jth column of a Pascal's triangle in O(1) time

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pascals-triangle

The sum of the elements of the ith row of Pascal's triangle is 2^n. How can we find the sum of the elements of the ith row up to the jth column of Pascal's triangle in O(1) time?

The solutions that came to my mind is not O(1). The recursive combination function for the nth row of Pascal's triangle. nCk = n-1Ck + n-1Ck-1

Comment: There is also `nCk = n! / ((n - k)! * k!)`. Not sure what `O(1)` means here (how does factorial count?).

Comment: The fastest solution I can think of would be flipping bits, but that's still O(n) bit flips (where `n=j-i`).

Comment: Exactly my point, all the solutions like above are not **O(1)** solutions to the problem. **O(1)** here means that the problem can be solved in constant time, hence I can't use recursion, factorial, etc.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that for large n, the binomial distribution B(n, 0.5) probabilities can be approximated using a normal distribution. This won't give an exact answer, but maybe there is some way to bound the error for sufficiently large n such that the rounded answer will be exact. The question is better suited for https://mathoverflow.net/ anyway.